# How to emulate "mv --no-clobber" in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, mv

As the name implies, the `--no-clobber` (or `-n`) flag of the `mv` command (at least the Gnu version) causes the command to fail if the requested move would have overwritten an existing file.

How can this be emulated in a Windows batch file?

(BTW, the projected batch file is intended to run automatically (i.e. unsupervised), so any solution that entails prompting a human user for permission is out.)

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
> MOVE /?
Moves files and renames files and directories.

To move one or more files:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination

To rename a directory:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]dirname1 dirname2

  [drive:][path]filename1 Specifies the location and name of the file
                          or files you want to move.
  destination             Specifies the new location of the file. Destination
                          can consist of a drive letter and colon, a
                          directory name, or a combination. If you are moving
                          only one file, you can also include a filename if
                          you want to rename the file when you move it.
  [drive:][path]dirname1  Specifies the directory you want to rename.
  dirname2                Specifies the new name of the directory.

  /Y                      Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to
                          overwrite an existing destination file.
  /-Y                     Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite
                          an existing destination file.

The switch /Y may be present in the COPYCMD environment variable.
This may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.  Default is
to prompt on overwrites unless MOVE command is being executed from
within a batch script.

> ECHO N | MOVE /-Y OLDFILE NEWFILE
```

Alternatively:

```
IF NOT EXIST NEWFILE MOVE OLDFILE NEWFILE
```

Combined with a FOR loop for multiple files.